# Navigation bar not working properly

Tags: html, css, frontend, nav, web-frontend

When I put my cursor right on top of the link text, the link is not clickable, but if I put my cursor a little bit below the text, it becomes clickable. I'm learning right now so please explain to me why it's doing that and how to fix it.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html Lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Welcome!</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
```

```css
    *{
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    header{
      width: 1024px;
      margin: 0 auto;
      background-color: #81D4FA;
      height: 50px;
    }
    header h1{
      color: white;
      position: relative;
      left: 100px;
      top: 5px;
    }
    nav{
      margin-top: -20px;
      margin-right: 100px;
    }
    
    nav ul{
      float: right;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    
    nav ul li{
      list-style-type: none;
        display: inline-block;
    }
    
    nav ul li a{
      text-decoration: none;
      color: white;
      padding: 16px 20px;
    }
    a:hover{
      background-color: #84FFFF;
    }
    .main{
      width: 1024px;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
    }
    .laptop{
      width: 1024px;
    }
    .title{
      background-color: #0D23FD;
      height: 50px;
      width: 300px;
      position: relative;
      top: -650px;
      left: -10px;
      border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
      border-top-right-radius: 10px;
    }
    .title h3{
      color: white;
      text-align: center;
      position: relative;
      top: 13px;
    }
```

```html
      <header>
        <h1>Jack Smith</h1>
          <nav>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">My Work</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Contact Me</a></li>
            </ul>
          </nav>
      </header>
        <div class="main">
          <img class="laptop" src="images/laptop.jpg">
          <div class="title">
            <h3>Front-End Web developer</h3>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because your `<h1>` is a block-level element, which will lay over the menu elements. If you give it `display: inline-block`, it will work as supposed.

> A **block-level element** always starts on a new line and takes up the
>   full width available (stretches out to the left and right as far as it
>   can).

See my example below.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
header {
  width: 1024px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #81D4FA;
  height: 50px;
}
header h1 {
  color: white;
  position: relative;
  left: 100px;
  top: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  /* Added */
}
nav {
  margin-top: -20px;
  margin-right: 100px;
}
nav ul {
  float: right;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
nav ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline-block;
}
nav ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px 20px;
}
a:hover {
  background-color: #84FFFF;
}
.main {
  width: 1024px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
.laptop {
  width: 1024px;
}
.title {
  background-color: #0D23FD;
  height: 50px;
  width: 300px;
  position: relative;
  top: -650px;
  left: -10px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
}
.title h3 {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  top: 13px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>Jack Smith</h1>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">About</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">My Work</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact Me</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
<div class="main">
  <img class="laptop" src="images/laptop.jpg">
  <div class="title">
    <h3>Front-End Web developer</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is occurring because of the interaction between some of your styles. You're floating the `nav ul` element to the right, but you're also setting the `nav ul li` display to `inline-block` which is also doing an implicit float (try replacing it with `float: left` and you'll see the same behavior).

If you set the `position:relative` on your `nav ul`, it willforce the elements to float correctly within the `ul` container.

```
nav ul{
  float: right;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position:relative; /*ADD THIS*/
}
```